# Updating heartbeat mysql resource in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, heartbeat

I have a HA setup on two Ubuntu 10.04 machines with Heartbeat/Pacemaker running fine except for the mysql resource is not the most up to date version. The one I have does not include the promote/demote features and I'm having trouble getting the most current version. I feel I'm missing something simple or am doing something wrong here and feel dumb but the help is greatly appreciated.